# Listview reload when filter

Tags: api, listview, flutter, dart

I have a listview builder which contents gets populated initially on a api call.

```
Container(
              child: RefreshIndicator(
                onRefresh: getOrderData,
                child: LoadMore(child:
                ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _bookingData.bookingData == null
                        ?  Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),)
                        : _bookingData.bookingData.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
                         (context)=>BookingDetails(_bookingData.bookingData[index]
                          )));},
                          child: (widget.formattedDate == null&&widget.bookId == null) ?
                          // List()


                          ListPopUP(_bookingData.bookingData[index])
```

I want to filter the list by date . so i need to do another api request. now i want to reload the listview based on the api response. how can i achieve that

Comment: you can use either empty setState call or giving Listview a UniqueKey

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply InheritedWidget and define a static method like "of" with `setState((/*...*/) {/*...*/});` in it then call from another place

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a StreamBuilder if you are expecting regular updates to your listview?